# count number of times string appears in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize

Can you think about an intuitive way of calculating the number of times the word space appears in a certain column? Or any other solution that is viable.
I basically want to know how many times the space key was pressed, however some participants made the mistake and pressed other keys which would also be considered a mistake. So I was wondering if I should go with the "key_resp.rt" column instead and count the number of response times instead. If you had any idea of how to do both it would be great as I may need to use both.

I used the following code but the results do not conform to the data.

```
 Data %>% group_by(Participant, Session) %>% summarise(false_start = sum(str_count(key_resp.keys, "space")))
```

Here is a snippet of my data:

```
    Participant    RT     Session   key_resp.keys           key_resp.rt
       X        0.431265    1       ["space"]            [2.3173399999941466]
       X        0.217685    1           
       X        0.317435    2       ["space","space"] [0.6671900000001187,2.032510000000002]    2020.1.3    4
       Y        0.252515    1       
       Y        0.05127     2   ["space","space","space","space","space","space","space","space","space"]   [4.917419999999765,6.151149999999689,6.333714999999771,6.638249999999971,6.833514999999338,7.0362499999992,7.217724999999504,7.38576999999988,7.66913999999997]
```

```
dput(droplevels(head(Data_PVT)))
structure(list(Interval_stimulus = c(4.157783411, 4.876139922, 
5.67011868, 9.338167417, 9.196342656, 7.62448411), Participant = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ADH80254", class = "factor"), 
    RT = c(431.265, 277.99, 253.515, 310.53, 299.165, 539.46), 
    Session = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2020-06-12_11h11.47.141", class = "factor"), 
    key_resp.keys = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "[\"space\"]"), class = "factor"), key_resp.rt = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "[2.3173399999941466]"
    ), class = "factor"), psychopyVersion = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2020.1.3", class = "factor"), 
    Trials = 0:5, Reciprocal = c(2.31875992719094, 3.59725169970143, 
    3.94453977082224, 3.22030077609249, 3.3426370063343, 1.85370555740926
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
Participant  Session  false_start
   x             1       0
   x             2       1
   y             1       2
   y             2       1
   z             1       10
   z             2       3
```

Comment: well, I am not sure how to reproduce this. The key_resp.keys column either has nothing in it (if no key is pressed, ["space"] if the key is pressed once, or ["space", "space",...] for how many times it was pressed. Not sure how to reproduce this. Key_resp.rt follows the same logic and presents the response times in the same format. Sorry I cannot be more helpful.

Comment: Sorry the formatting is terrible, not sure how to make it better.

Comment: I just put a bit of it, there will be entries for session 1 and those for session 2.

Comment: Just added the information you asked for.

Comment: In the first 6 rows in the dput, there is only the first row havng `["space"]`, others are blank.  what is the expected output

Comment: the expected output for those would be 1 for the one with space and 0 for the blank ones. One point per word "space"

Comment: In that case, I get the expected with `Data_PVT  %>% mutate(false_start  = str_count(key_resp.keys, "\\bspace\\b"))`

Comment: Based on your code sample, here's a solution that groups your variables and counts: `df %>% group_by(Participant, Session) %>% summarise(false_start = grep("\\<space\\>", key_resp.keys))`.

Comment: @akrun I checked and it seems like it is giving the double of the amount of words, is that possible? I can divide it by 2, but I am unable to check if this is the case for all of them.

Comment: @hmhensen It gave me the following error: Error: Column `false_start` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 10

Comment: @CatM Weird, it's working just fine when I run it on the `dput` you provided.

Comment: It works with akrun's code, but gives the double amount, do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: I get 1, 0, 0, 0, . for the example.  Not clear how you are getting `double amount`

Comment: @akrun I used the following: PVT_desc <- Data_PVT %>% group_by(Participant, Session) %>%   mutate(false_start  = str_count(key_resp.keys, "\\bspace\\b")) %>%
  summarise(lapses = sum(RT >500), mean_PVT = mean(RT), mean_recip = mean(Reciprocal), False = sum(false_start))

Comment: You don't need the group by before the `str_count`

Comment: Based on your code, I get a single row of summarised output

Comment: That's because there are more than 40 rows for participant, so the dput you asked for was just for one participant and hence only one row emerged when you used my code.

Comment: Anything other than "reproducible question please" is encouraging another bad question.

Comment: @akrun It was giving double the amount as the dataframe contained the same data twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_count` to count `"space"` values for each `Participant` and `Session` and `sum` them to get total. For `all_false_start` we count number of words in it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(Participant, Session) %>%
  summarise(false_start = sum(str_count(key_resp.keys, '\\bspace\\b')), 
            all_false_start = sum(str_count(key_resp.keys, '\\b\\w+\\b')))
```

Comment: But I want to know how many times they pressed space.

Comment: How do you define "pressing space" ?

Comment: Well, if we are talking about pressing only the key "space" then it would be the number of times the word space appears in each row. If we are talking about all key presses, then it would be the number of response times in the variable key_resp.rt

Comment: No, we are talking about what you want to calculate. I am confused about it. The example which you have shared does not have enough observation to match your expected output. You can remove other columns which are not necessary for the question and share `dput` of more rows with expected output so that the question becomes clear.

Comment: That's why I tried to produce some sample of the necessary columns in the "snippet of the data". That's what it looks like but with more rows per participant.

Comment: PVT_desc <- Data_PVT %>% mutate(false_start  = str_count(key_resp.keys, "\\bspace\\b")) %>%
  group_by(Participant, Session) %>%
  summarise(lapses = sum(RT >500), mean_PVT = mean(RT), mean_recip = mean(Reciprocal), False = sum(false_start)/2)

Comment: This code works but gives twice the amount of false_starts as it should hence why I divide the sum by two, not sure why that is.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to calculate and what is the logic to calculate it? We can write the code for you but what you are trying to calculate should be defined by you. Also the columns `Interval_stimulus`, `date`, `psychopyVersion`, `Trials` and `Reciprocal` don;t seem relevant to question.

Comment: Yes, I only care about Participant, Session, key_resp.keys and key_resp.rt for this. I want to get the sum value of the number of times a participant pressed a key when he shouldn't, i.e. the number of times the word "space" appears in the key_resp.keys (if we only care about the word space) or any word (if we care that they might have pressed other keys). So I thought I would get the number of times a key is pressed per row and then sum that for all rows for each participant.

Comment: @CatM  Let's leave `Session` for now. What would be your expected output for this dataframe? `df <- data.frame(Participant = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),                   key_resp.keys = c('[space]', 'a', '[space][space][space]', 'a', '', 'b', '[space][space]', ''))` ?

Comment: It would be the following, where false_start only includes space and all_false_start includes all.      df <- data.frame(Participant = c(1, 2), false_start = c(4,2), all_false_start = c(6,3))

Comment: @CatM should `all_false_start` for 1st `ID` be 5? See updated answer.

Comment: all_false_start  for the ID 1 would be 6, i.e. pressing the key "space" (4x) and "a" (2x)

Comment: @CatM Okay...see updated answer. I hope I get it this time.